# OkHttp3: Getting an 'unexpected end of stream' exception while reading a large HTTP response

Tags: http, okhttp, hasura

I have a Java client, that is making a POST call to the v1/graphql endpoint of a Hasura server (v1.3.3)

I'm making the HTTP call using the Square okhttp3 library (v4.9.1). The data transfer is happening over HTTP1.1, using chunked transfer-encoding.

The client is failing with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$ChunkedSource.read(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:415) ~[okhttp-4.9.1.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange$ResponseBodySource.read(Exchange.kt:276) ~[okhttp-4.9.1.jar:?]
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.kt:189) ~[okio-jvm-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.exhausted(RealBufferedSource.kt:197) ~[okio-jvm-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at okio.InflaterSource.refill(InflaterSource.kt:112) ~[okio-jvm-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at okio.InflaterSource.readOrInflate(InflaterSource.kt:76) ~[okio-jvm-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at okio.InflaterSource.read(InflaterSource.kt:49) ~[okio-jvm-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at okio.GzipSource.read(GzipSource.kt:69) ~[okio-jvm-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at okio.Buffer.writeAll(Buffer.kt:1642) ~[okio-jvm-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readString(RealBufferedSource.kt:95) ~[okio-jvm-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.kt:187) ~[okhttp-4.9.1.jar:?]
```

Request Headers:

```
INFO: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
INFO: Content-Length: 1928
INFO: Host: localhost:10191
INFO: Connection: Keep-Alive
INFO: Accept-Encoding: gzip
INFO: User-Agent: okhttp/4.9.1
```

Response headers:

```
INFO: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
INFO: Date: Tue, 27 Apr 2021 12:06:39 GMT
INFO: Server: Warp/3.3.10
INFO: x-request-id: d019408e-e2e3-4583-bcd6-050d4a496b11
INFO: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
INFO: Content-Encoding: gzip
```

This is the client code used for the making the POST call:

```
private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .addNetworkInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .build();


public GenericHttpResponse httpPost(String url, String textBody, GenericHttpMediaType genericMediaType) throws HttpClientException {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(okHttpMediaType, textBody);
    Request postRequest = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(body).build();
    Call postCall = okHttpClient.newCall(okHttpRequest);
    Response postResponse = postCall.execute();
    return GenericHttpResponse
                .builder()
                .body(okHttpResponse.body().string())
                .headers(okHttpResponse.headers().toMultimap())
                .code(okHttpResponse.code())
                .build();
}
```

This failure is only happening for large response sizes. As per the server logs, the response size (after gzip encoding) is around 52MB, but the call is still failing. This same code has been working fine for response sizes around 10-15MB.

I tried replicating the same issue through a simple cURL call, but that ran successfully:

```
curl -v -s --request POST 'http://<hasura_endpoint>/v1/graphql' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
--data-raw '...'

*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <host> (::1) port <port> (#0)
> POST /v1/graphql HTTP/1.1
> Host: <host>:<port>
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Content-Length: 1840
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
} [1840 bytes data]
* We are completely uploaded and fine

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 27 Apr 2021 11:59:24 GMT
< Server: Warp/3.3.10
< x-request-id: 27e3ff3f-8b95-4328-a1bc-a5492e68f995
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Encoding: gzip
<
{ [6 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host <host> left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

So I'm assuming that this error is specific to the Java client.

Based on suggestions provided in similar posts, I tried the following other approaches:

1. Adding a `Connection: close` header to the request
2. Sending `Transfer-Encoding: gzip` header in the request
3. Setting the `retryOnConnectionFailure` for the OkHttp client to `true`

But none of these approaches were able to resolve the issue.

So, my questions are:

1. What could be the underlying cause for this issue? Since I'm using chunked transfer encoding here, I suppose it's not due to an incorrect content-length header passed in the response.
2. What are the approaches I can try for debugging this further?

Would really appreciate any insights on this. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that query itself is OK? Can you run it in hasura UI to be sure? Timed out queries sometimes looks like incorrectly encoded json output. Something like that braces `{`/`}` are not closed. I saw that several times,  then correction of query or index optimization and problem gone. And you wrote about "large output" - so that could be the case.

Comment: I suggest you to doubt succes of curl query. Redirect output to file and then try to decode that json. I expect that it will be not having closing braces.

Comment: Maybe it's not Java client to blame. We are using apollo for frontend and different clients for backend. Jupyter notebooks for documentation we use python/gql as common denominator. I can recommend it for debugging purposes.